# Using named-parameter flavor of #each helper together with a generic partial

Tags: ember.js

In my application I have different node types, which share a similar structure. For that I am using a template like this:

```
{{#each model}}
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    ... {{! more properties specific to this node (agent) }}
    {{partial "common/output_cells"}}
{{/each}}
```

With `common/output_cells` being:

```
{{#if controller.startnodeAllowed}}<td>{{#if outputs§startnode}}{{#link-to startNodeRoute outputs§startnode}}{{view "nodeIcon" nodeIdBinding="outputs§startnode"}}{{/link-to}}{{else}}{{view "nodeIcon"}}{{/if}}</td>{{/if}}
... {{! other common properties for all nodes (lots of them)}}
```

Now I am transitioning to [named-parameter helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_more-consistent-handlebars-scope), so I have:

```
{{#each agent in content}}
    <td>{{agent.name}}</td>
    ... {{! more properties specific to this node (agent) }}
    {{partial "common/output_cells"}}
{{/each}}
```

And I am forced to change the common partial:

```
{{#if controller.startnodeAllowed}}<td>{{#if agent.outputs§startnode}}{{#link-to agent.startNodeRoute agent.outputs§startnode}}{{view "nodeIcon" nodeIdBinding="agent.outputs§startnode"}}{{/link-to}}{{else}}{{view "nodeIcon"}}{{/if}}</td>{{/if}}
... {{! other common properties for all nodes (lots of them)}}
```

But this makes my `common/output_cells` partial tied to an agent, while it should be tied to a generic node. Is it possible to call partial as follows (I made up the syntax, since I do not know how to do this)?

```
{{partial "common/output_cells" with agent as node}}
```

So that I can implement the partial in a more generic way:

```
{{#if controller.startnodeAllowed}}<td>{{#if node.outputs§startnode}}{{#link-to node.startNodeRoute node.outputs§startnode}}{{view "nodeIcon" nodeIdBinding="node.outputs§startnode"}}{{/link-to}}{{else}}{{view "nodeIcon"}}{{/if}}</td>{{/if}}
... {{! other common properties for all nodes (lots of them)}}
```

If this is not possible, what other options do I have in order to reuse the partial?

Comment: Consider using the with helper.

Comment: @torazaburo Is the with helper documented? The each helper is (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/), but i can find nothing about the with helper.

Comment: The guides are not comprehensive; try the API docs instead. `{{with}}` is at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `{{with}}`:

```
{{#each agent in content}}
    <td>{{agent.name}}</td>
    ... {{! more properties specific to this node (agent) }}

    {{#with agent}}
        {{partial "common/output_cells"}}
    {{/with}}

{{/each}}
```

To put it a different away, since this flavor of `{{#each}}` doesn't change the context, change the context yourself, which is what `{{#with}}` does.

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_with.